# Filling a CSS Grid from bottom up instead of top down

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors, css-grid

I need a way for the elements in my CSS Grid to stack upwards instead of top down.

[image: Top down to Bottom up grid]

Here's what I have so far:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  width: 306px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.gridItem {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="gridItem">1</div>
  <div class="gridItem">2</div>
  <div class="gridItem">3</div>
  <div class="gridItem">4</div>
  <div class="gridItem">5</div>
  <div class="gridItem">6</div>
  <div class="gridItem">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure that is possible, not with reflow.  The CSS algorithm was designed with the idea of an infinitely long page, so layout starts at the top and works its way down.

Comment: What do you know in advance? For example, is the number of elements known?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use flexbox:

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap-reverse; /* this will do the magic */
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.gridItem {
  width:calc(100%/3);
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="gridItem">1</div>
  <div class="gridItem">2</div>
  <div class="gridItem">3</div>
  <div class="gridItem">4</div>
  <div class="gridItem">5</div>
  <div class="gridItem">6</div>
  <div class="gridItem">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know exact number of divs you can try with grid areas:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  width: 306px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.gridItem {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
.div1 { grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2; }
.div2 { grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3; }
.div3 { grid-area: 3 / 3 / 4 / 4; }
.div4 { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2; }
.div5 { grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3; }
.div6 { grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4; }
.div7 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="gridItem div1">1</div>
  <div class="gridItem div2">2</div>
  <div class="gridItem div3">3</div>
  <div class="gridItem div4">4</div>
  <div class="gridItem div5">5</div>
  <div class="gridItem div6">6</div>
  <div class="gridItem div7">7</div>
</div>
```